# PHPUnit_Framework_BaseTestListener class not found

Tags: drupal, phpunit

I am trying to run a PHPunit test for my extension but I keep getting the following error:
`Fatal error: Class 'PHPUnit_Framework_BaseTestListener' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\myDrupalsite\sites\all\modules\civicrm\Civi\Test\CiviTestListener.php on line 17`
Any ideas on how I can fix this?
I am using CiviCRM 4.7
CMS is Drupal 7
My system OS is Windows 10. 
My extension is placed in `<Drupal root>sites/default/files/civicrm/ext`
My test directory was created using `civix generate:test` on the Windows command prompt.
I run the tests using PHPUnit via the command prompt in the root directory of my extension.

Comment: Hi Fanan, welcome to CiviCRM Stack Exchange. It helps if you add more detail to your question. Standard is the used CiviCRM version and the accompanying CMS. For this question, you can add how you run the test and more details about your development environment.

Comment: Hi Fanan, impressive that you have it running on Windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I run tests the following way

1. I test in a CiviCRM instance that is generated with buildkit (the toolchain provided for CiviCRM developers see https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/tools/buildkit/ .
2. My tests are generated with `civix generate:test`. Remarks that this generator also creates the file `tests/phpunit/bootstrap.php` that takes care of the class loading.
3. I run the test from the extension directory by executing `phpunit4` (This version is installed with buildkit).

Comment: This worked fine although when I use ``phpunit`` instead of ``phpunit4`` I still get the error ``Fatal error: Class 'PHPUnit_Framework_BaseTestListener' not found in ...``

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a mismatch in the phpunit versions:

- Currently, most of the Civi testing runs against the PHAR build of `phpunit` v4.
- `phpunit` v6 [renames every class](https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/wiki/Release-Announcement-for-PHPUnit-6.0.0) to use `\` instead of `_`, which means that all the base-classes disappear if you run on a newer build of phpunit.

Comment: Thanks Tim, this gives a good motivation why phpunit4 is used.